# How to program for bluetooth with Mobile Web frameworks like sencha touch

Tags: web-applications, mobile, bluetooth, sencha-touch

We are starting a new project at work, and we need to build a cross-platform mobile application. A big requirement for this application is the ability to interface with hardware via bluetooth. I'm wondering if there is a way to build a cross-platform web app using Senchatouch+phonegap, and have the ability to interface with the bluetooth. My guess is that each bluetooth module would have to be platform specific (which is ok) as long as there is a way to incorporate that with the cross-platform potion of the application.

Thanks, let me know if you need any more information.